# phonegap local notification

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, local

i have implemented a local notification in my android app using phonegap 
localnotification plugin.

notification get trigger properly but while clicking on notification
app does not open.

what i want to relaunch a app on clicking of status notification.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AlarmReciever class, in onRecieve event, change the line 79,

```
final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
```

to

```
final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context,mainActivity.class), 0);
```

It starts, new activity